# Thinktecture Identity Server HRD

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server

I would like to use Thinktecture identity server V2 "WS-Federation HRD" to let users can login with Facebook account or the identity server I created by Thinktecture identity server.
the following is my use case. I also refer the https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/issues/484 to try to config my Thinkecture identity server, 
it can show the HRD login page and I can login successful but it always redirect to the Thinktecture identity server Home page not to the client application after I login successful.

Can anyone tell me the how can I configurate it on Thinktecture Identity Server and the ASP.NET MVC Client Application configuration?

***use case**:*

1.(APP Client)abc.cloudapp.net/oauthclient2/

2.=> Thinktecture identity server "hrd" page (https://def.cloudapp.net/identityserver/ )

3.=> login with facebook or IDP(identity server) if successful then

4.=> redirect to (APP Client)abc.cloudapp.net/oauthclient2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide that you mentioned is OK. The problem you might have is at the last screen.

Try to set Redirect URL back to your application (abc.cloudapp.net/oauthclient2/) in the relaying party for your application (abc.cloudapp.net/oauthclient2/).

Comment: thanks pepo, i have already solved my problem and post the solution on Thinktecture Identity Server github : https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/issues/651